# Double char array mapping to QImage

Tags: qt, qimage

Im having a double pointer char of dataBuffer[1000][1000] 
in that char pointer some places i will make hex value 0xFF and remaining 0x00 (for openGL plotting)

now i want it to show it as a QWidget with the hex value in pixel.

i found QImage we can map 1000x1000 pixels but i dont know how to map hex value of char to pixels .

please help me ,
 thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do the following:

First, construct `QImage` from your buffer using this constructor: `QImage(const uchar* data, int width, int height, Format format)`, using `QImage::Format_Indexed8` as `format` i.e.

```
QImage img(dataBuffer, 1000, 1000, QImage::Format_Indexed8)
```

Second, Initialize color translation map: it should be `QVector<QRgb>`, so you need to do something like this:

```
QVector<QRgb> colorMap(256);
colorMap[255] = QRgb(255, 255, 255); // Any color of your choice
// probably some other mappings
```

Then use `QImage::convertToFormat` like this:

```
QImage converted = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32, colorMap)
```

This will convert it to RGB. Basically, that's it, now you can draw this image on your widget or save it to file.

Comment: First tnx for ur best reply ..  but im facing some problem in implementing ur logic .  QVector<QRgb> colorMap(256);
colorMap[255] = QRgb(255, 255, 255); throws me an error : Expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast[-F premissive].. can u please help me in sort this out .. thx once again :)

Comment: I Fixed it  sir... for(int row =0; row < 2048; row ++)
        for(int column =0; column < 2048; column ++)
        { m_dataArray[row][column] = 0x00;

        }

    QImage img(*m_dataArray, 2048, 2048, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

    QVector<QRgb> colortable(256);

    colortable[255] = qRgb(255,255,255);  QImage converted = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32, colortable);



    m_graphicsScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(converted));

Comment: Thx user2155932 for reply. this is what i did a double ponter unsigned char array unsigned char **m_dataArray; and i plotted it as http://pastebin.com/vVRetzPA but the image looks little odd as it has white spots on a black image.
Please help me to resolve it. .